# User to User Messages in Rails 5: Assigning message to receiver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am attempting to set up a messaging system in my rails app that will allow the receiver to view their messages on a separate page. So far I have been able to set up everything so the message will successfully send however the issue is that it won't assign itself to the message receiver, noted as "receiver_id". As I currently have implemented a "relationships" model that keeps track of followers/following, I have tried to use that model as a way to assign the user but it hasn't worked out either yet. Please see my code below:

Message Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
 #before_action :set_receiver, only: [:new, :create]


 def create
  @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
  #@message.receiver_id = @receiver.id
  if @message.save!
     flash[:success] = "message sent!"
     redirect_to root_url
  else 
     render 'new'
  end
 end 

 def new
  @message = current_user.messages_received.new
  #@receiver_id = :followed_id

 end 

 def view
 end 

 def destroy
 end 

 def index
  @message = current.user.messages
 end 

 def show
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
 end 

 private

  def message_params
   params.require(:message).permit(:content, :receiver_id, :sender_id).merge(sender_id: current_user.id) #.merge(receiver_id: followed_id.id)
  end
```

Message.rb

```
    class Message < ApplicationRecord
  #belongs_to :user, optional: true, :foreign_key=> 'user_id'
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name=>'User', :foreign_key=>'sender_id'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name=>'User', optional: true, :foreign_key=>'receiver_id'
  scope :unread, -> { where read: false}
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :messages_sent, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: :sender_id
has_many :messages_received, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: :receiver_id
has_many :messages
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Send Message") %>
<h1> Send Message </h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class= "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "message", object: f.object %>

  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'password_resets/new'
  get 'password_resets/edit'
  get 'sessions/new'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/privacy',   to: 'static_pages#privacy'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new' 
  get  '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  get  '/message', to: 'messages#new'
  post '/message?id=USER_ID', to: 'messages#create'
  get  '/view_message', to: 'messages#view'
  get  'auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#callback'
  post  '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers, :messages
    end 
  end 
  resources :user do
    get :profile
     resource :messages, only: [:new, :create]
    end 


  resources :message, only: [:new, :create, :show] 
<% end %>
```

_follow_form.html.erb

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
   <div id= "follow_form">
   <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
     <%= render 'unfollow' %>
    <%= link_to "Send Message", message_path(@user), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %>
   <% else %>
     <%= render 'follow' %>
   <% end %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: question is pretty broad right now, what in particular isn't working here?

Comment: What is broad about the question? I stated that the message isn't being assigned to the receiver.  For example, after posting a message on another user's page, the "Message Sent!" comes up however if you check the database, the receiver_id is still blank. I would like the message receiver to be assigned to the receiver_id field.

Comment: Try adding  `<%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id %>` to your 'send message' form. Let me know if it works I will make an answer. Check the `message_params` in `def create` to make sure it includes `receiver_id`

Comment: That doesn't work either....the receiver_id field is still blank

Comment: You should check each step along the way. Make sure that `@message` has the receiver_id field set when you render the form. And check the value of `message_params` to make sure it's passed. Beyond that, I don't have any other further advice, sorry. It's a good idea to pick up a debugger like `pry` or `byebug`.